# How to attach to WSL shared library in Visual Studio 2019 cmake project

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, windows-subsystem-for-linux

We have a CMake VS2019 C++ project building a shared library for Linux. Our main ASP net core application is loading this shared library. We would like to know how to debug this on WSL. Below is our launch config in Visual Studio 2019

```
{
   "version": "0.2.1",
   "defaults": {},
   "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "cppgdb",
       "name": "engine",
       "MIMode": "gdb",
       "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
       "projectTarget": "libengine.so",
       "debuggerConfiguration": "gdb",
       "args": [],
       "env": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

If the C++ project was an executable then we can just start it directly from the CMake project but its a shared library so we can't do this. How can we attach to the shared library from the CMake project? Actually the issue seems to be we can't find the running ASP Net core app in the list of processes when using the 'Attach to Process' menu option. We are assuming we don't need to SSH to WSL2.

Answer (score 0):

We had to SSH into the WSL2 system using the Remote Connection Manager in Visual Studio. Then we could attach to the ASP net app and choose Native(GDB). It would be nice to be able to step into C++ from C# directly but at least this gives us a way forward.